# Linked List remove method by value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Trying to get this linked list remove method to work. should remove a node from the middle if that is where the value is found, and preserve the rest of the sequence. should not modify the list sequence if the last node is the node to be removed. it also should replace the start node with the second node when the first node value is x and the remove function is called with the value x.

```
remove(valueToRemove) {
   let currentNode = this.firstNode;
   let previousNode;

   let foundValue = valueToRemove = currentNode.value;
   while (!foundValue) {
     previousNode = currentNode;
     currentNode = currentNode.next;

     if (!currentNode) {
       return;
     }

     foundValue = valueToRemove === currentNode.value;
   }

   let nextNode = currentNode.next;

   if (currentNode === this.firstNode) {
     this.firstNode = nextNode;
   } else {
     previousNode.next = nextNode;
   }
   this.listSize--;
 }
```

Comment: The mistake is in the line let foundValue = valueToRemove = currentNode.value ( make it ===)

Comment: Please show the more complete code so we can reproduce your issue. Right now, we don't have any clue as to what `this` would reference. Include the relevant HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: You also need to include the actual vs expected behavior.

Comment: @Scott Marcus it's related to a data structures, linked-list, has nothing to do with html or css and this references the current node that linked-list is iterating through

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS I understand what the question is about. We always like to have people post a create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This allows us to replicate the issue and more easily provide a working answer.

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS That was it! now working thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the below code you are equating the values hence overriding the valueToRemove

```
 let foundValue = valueToRemove = currentNode.value;
```

change it to

```
let foundValue = valueToRemove === currentNode.value;
```